# "KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME' ", "can't load main class from JAR" in running PySpark as an Oozie workflow job

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, pyspark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

This issue is a continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450828/oozie-job-wont-run-if-using-pyspark-in-sparkaction), which was seemingly resolved but leads to here as another issue.

I am using Spark 1.4.0 on Cloudera QuickstartVM CHD-5.4.0.
When I run my PySpark script as a SparkAction in Oozie, I encounter this error in the Oozie job / container logs:

```
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'
```

Then I came across [this solution](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6506) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6508) which are actually for Spark 1.3.0, although I still did try. The documentations seem to say that this issue is already fixed for Spark version 1.3.2 and 1.4.0 (but here I am, encountering the same issue).

The suggested solution in the link was that I need to set `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME` and `spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME` to anything, even if it's just any path that does not point to actual `SPARK_HOME` (i.e., `/bogus`, although I did set these to actual SPARK_HOME).

Here's my workflow after:

```
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>local[2]</master>
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>${name}</name>
        <jar>${workflowRootLocal}/lib/my_pyspark_job.py</jar>
        <spark-opts>--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark</spark-opts>
    </spark>
```

Which seems to solve the original problem above. However, it leads to another error when I try to inspect stderr of Oozie container log:

```
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1437103727449_0011/container_1437103727449_0011_01_000001/spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
```

If I am using Python, it should not expect for a `main class` right? Please note in my previous related post that the Oozie job example shipped with Cloudera QuickstartVM CDH-5.4.0, which features a SparkAction written in Java was working in my tests. It seems that the issue is only in Python.

Appreciate greatly anyone that can help.

Comment: am getting error like this "Error: SPARK_HOME does not exist for python application in yarn mode." any idea abt this ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME and spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME variables, try and add the following lines of code to your python script before setting your SparkConf()

```
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/path/to/spark/installed/location"
```

Found the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566250/keyerror-spark-home-during-sparkconf-initialization)

This helped me resolve the error you face, but I faced the following error afterwards

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py", line 60, in main
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 107, in __init__
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 155, in _do_init
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 201, in _initialize_context
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 701, in __call__
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```