# KeyError: SPARK_HOME during SparkConf initialization

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a spark newbie and I want to run a Python script from the command line. I have tested pyspark interactively and it works. I get this error when trying to create the sc:

```
File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    conf=(SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('a').setSparkHome('/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin'))
  File "/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/context.py", line 229, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 48, in launch_gateway
    SPARK_HOME = os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like there are two problems here.

The first one is a path you use. `SPARK_HOME` should point to the root directory of the Spark installation so in your case it should probably be `/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6` not `/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin`.

The second problem is a way how you use `setSparkHome`. If you check [a docstring](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/python/pyspark/conf.py#L130) its goal is to

> set path where Spark is installed on worker nodes

`SparkConf` constructor assumes that `SPARK_HOME` on master is already set. [It calls](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/python/pyspark/conf.py#L104) `pyspark.context.SparkContext._ensure_initialized` [which calls](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/49351c7f597c67950cc65e5014a89fad31b9a6f7/python/pyspark/context.py#L234) `pyspark.java_gateway.launch_gateway`, [which tries to acccess](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/49351c7f597c67950cc65e5014a89fad31b9a6f7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py#L48) `SPARK_HOME` and fails.

To deal with this you should set `SPARK_HOME` before you create `SparkConf`.

```
import os
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6"
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('a'))
```

Comment: What if I am trying to connect to a remote machine? And setting "SPARK_HOME" when trying to run a client(in this case *pyspark*) doesn't really make sense, does it? Shouldn't this be removed?